# Python Popen can't open bash shell in CentOS/Red Hat

Tags: python, bash, centos, debian, redhat

I can't open a bash shell in CentOS with python 2.7, I'm able to do so in python 2.6.6 Debian. What has changed?

I tried a simple bash process substitution:

```
from subprocess import Popen
cmd="""cat <<'EOF'
this is
test $unchanged
EOF
"""
Popen('cat <(%s)' % cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

In Debian this works, in CentOS it doesn't:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(cat <<'EOF''
```

The differences are:

- **Debian**: Python 2.6.6, `/bin/sh` is provided by dash.
- **CenOS** (Red Hat): Python 2.7, `/bin/sh` is provided by bash

So in CentOS the `executable=/bin/bash` is not being honored at all.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to replace `cat <(%s)' % cmd` to `cmd`.

Comment: @werehuman that's the test to see if bash is being started, `sh` can do redirection but not process substitution which I need for something different.

Comment: Ok, what if you write /bin/bash in arguments? ``Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'cat <(%s)' % cmd])``

Comment: @werehuman that does work indeed! That's what the execute flag should be doing... no idea why is not

Comment: I have no CentOS machine but i'm think that there is something wrong with bash.

Comment: @werehuman I can't find anything strange with bash, and the issue is that it's not being started at all...

Comment: I can't reproduce this (CentOS 7.0.1406/stock python 2.7.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you write /bin/bash in arguments?

```
Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'cat <(%s)' % cmd])
```

Comment: Thanks werehuman, this works. I hope some one can point out why this is required for Python 2.7 - Red hat.

Comment: Probably because input redirection is shell's work, bash in your case?