# Calling a shell script from python that requires a file without writing the file to disk

Tags: python, pipe, popen

For simplification purposes lets assume the shell script is the `cat` command. In the shell it would be normally called like this:

```
$ cat /some/path/myfile.txt
```

Now the file will be created dynamically and writing it to disk would be a major performance hit, present security issues and increase the file management overhead in a multiuser environment. The script cannot be modified nor can read from stdin (`cat` was just a working sample).

I tried this:

```
import os
pin, pout = os.pipe()
pin, pout = os.fdopen(pin, 'r'), os.fdopen(pout,'w')

from subprocess import Popen
pout.write("test")
pout.flush()
p = Popen('cat /proc/self/fd/%s' % pout.fileno(), shell=True)
```

Even if I close `pout` `p.poll()` still returns nothing showing that the command is still waiting more input from the pipe.

How can I tell the command there's no more data coming from the pipe?
Is there any other approach to solve this?

**Edit**

In bash, if the file content is generated by a program named `prog1` this would be solved in this manner:

```
$ cat <(prog1)
```

**Edit 2**

If you don't need the shell then the other option mentioned by Alfe is better, though the problem still exists (i.e. the process is not finishing after reading the file contents)

```
#...same as before
p = Popen(['cat', '/dev/stdin'], stdin=pout)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you don't find a good solution, consider using [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: @BlaXpirit tempfile is writing to disk, the only condition is not to do that. I'll edit the question and try to explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did at the end but is not nice.

Because I'm working on CentOS and the problem I'm having (I've asked about it here: [Python Popen can't open bash shell in CentOS/Red Hat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511422/python-popen-cant-open-bash-shell-in-centos-red-hat)) I can't use `execute='/bin/bash'` that's why the solution looks a little different than the question.

What I'm passing in some configuration to the process using bash process substitution and here-documents:

```
file_contents = '...'
p = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', "cat <(cat<<'EOF_CFG'\n%s\nEOF_CFG\n)" % file_contents])
```

I'm now considering using tmpfs for creating named pipes on it. I think that starting the script on it first and then writing to the pipe should work... If I'm successfull I'll write it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddled around a little bit, seems that closing the pipe on the one side does not generate an eof on the associated pseudo file /proc/self/fd/<#> of the child process.  Did you try it with /dev/stdin and simple piping your input to the subprocess's stdin?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The script being run expects a file and cannot read from stdin (that's why I said `cat` is only a simple example, the real script can't do that)

Comment: /dev/stdin is a fake-file which is associated with the current process's stdin.  Try:  `ls | cat file_a /dev/stdin file_b`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that! It's a better option, but it has just the same problem. There's no EOF being sent... The good thing is that it doesn't need the shell. Though in my particular case I need to source files, to setup the environment.

Comment: Actually you seem to have the problem that if a process (your consumer) opens a file instead of reading from a pipe, another process cannot signal it about closing the pipe (normally this would raise a SIGPIPE).  So there is no way for you to do what you want to do.  *Maybe* your consumer also can read from a pipe and will handle the SIGPIPE properly; in that case *maybe* he also handles it when reading from a file.  So you *could* try sending him that SIGPIPE manually.  But I would not bet on that all the maybes are going to work here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a named pipe for this.  On it, EOFs are properly propagated:

```
$ mkfifo bla
$ python
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen('cat bla', shell=True)
with file('bla', 'w') as f:
  f.write('test')
```

You can create named pipes on the fly from Python as well, of course, just use `os.mkfifo()`.

Comment: indeed that was my latest consideration. I have to check if that works in my particular case, because the Popen happens down in the class hierarchy and triggers a communicate which is expected to block until the script finishes. The subclass would then have to pass "something" that would act like a file. I have to try it out, but I think I'd need two processes for this,